# Vector with boldface and a hat on top

Tags: amsmath, vector, bm, boldmath

Could one of you help me on how to get the following: I need a boldface vector with a hat on top, something like the vector with boldface and a hat as below:

```
${\mathbf \hat{p}}$ or $\bm{\hat{p}}$
```

Both the above mentioned methods do NOT seem to work.

Comment: Try with this `$\boldsymbol{\hat{p}}$`

Comment: "do not seem to work" isn't  a helpful description, do you get an error, the correct characters but not bold, or wrong characters or ???

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have been more specific. The character p does not bold when used in conjunction with a hat.

Answer (score 7):

- If you want just the letter "p" to be rendered in bold while the "hat" symbol should be rendered in normal weight, you could use either one of the following methods:

  ```
  $\hat{\mathbf{p}}$,  $\hat{\bm{p}}$
  ```

  [image]

  Which method you should use depends on whether you want the letter "p" in upright-bold or slanted-bold.
- If both the letter "p" and the "hat" symbol should be typeset in bold, **and** the letter "p" should be in slanted-bold form, one of the following methods gets the job done.

  ```
  $\boldsymbol{\hat{p}}$, $\bm{\hat{p}}$
  ```

  [image]
- Finally, if you need the hat symbol to be bold **and** the letter "p" to be in upright-bold rather than in slanted-bold, try

  ```
  $\boldsymbol{\hat{\mathbf{p}}}$
  ```

  [image]

---

The full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm} % for \bm macro
\begin{document}
$\hat{\mathbf{p}}$ \quad  $\hat{\bm{p}}$ 

$\boldsymbol{\hat{p}}$ \quad $\bm{\hat{p}}$

$\boldsymbol{\hat{\mathbf{p}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've used (one of) the methods you've given, and it works now.